# unix- searching directory with execute permission

Tags: unix, permissions, find

I have execute permission only on a directory, which I believe means that I can search for a particular filename in that directory. However, when I'm in the directory and do:

```
     find . -name "file.txt"
```

I get a permission denied error for the directory. Which command should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` tries to read the directory, and you've said you don't have permission to read the directory.  The search permission on the directory means you have permission to access the files (subject to the permissions on the file itself, of course) if you know the name of the file.  The absence of read permission on the directory means that you cannot find out which files are in the directory except by trial-and-error or externally granted knowledge.

What do you want to do with the file?

- `cat file.txt` should work.
- `ls -l file.txt` should work.
- `cp file.txt /some/where/readable` should work.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. If I didn't know which subdirectory the file was in, but knew the filename, would it be possible to locate it using a recursive search>

Comment: It depends on whether you know the names of the sub-directories.  If you know them and their permissions allow you to read and search, then yes.  If you don't know the sub-directory names, or their permissions do not allow you to read them, you can try by direct access: `ls -l ./subdir1/file1.txt`.  Otherwise, you're back into trial-and-error searching.